# Compiling java file from different directory

Tags: java, linux, javac

I am very new to JAVA. I have written simple program (in Linux -VIM editor), compiled and executed it, everything is fine.

Now,I have moved that file to a different directory and am trying to compile(javac Myfile.java)  it, but it throws an error message as `javac-not found`.

Can somebody explain what is the problem?

Comment: yes,I guess...because when I simply create a java file and compile it with javac myfile.java- its compiling fine

Comment: Classpath, not properly set. Check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original question was not totally clear (since it did not contain the complete error message).

From your comment:

```
$ javac Example1.java
javac: file not found: Example1.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files> use -help for a list of possible options
```

So, javac did not find your file example java.

Normally, you should not have to set the CLASSPATH (use `export CLASSPATH=` in bash), and javac would search the source in the current directory. Is your `Example1.java` in the current directory? (Type `ls` and look at the output.)

If not, you should give the path to this file to javac as a parameter ... but it really is better so simply move to the right directory with `cd`.

If you are using packages, position your shell to the directory on top of the package directory hierarchy, and call the compiler with the relative filename from there.

---

Edit, since I see the next questions coming:

- The compiler will put the resulting class files in the output directory tree given by the `-d` parameter (or the current directory, if not given), by their package structure, so make sure you search them there later (when invoking the program).
- If the compiler needs other classes to compiler the files indicated in the command line, it searches class files in the classpath (given by the `-classpath` or `-cp` option, or by the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, or the current directory) and source files in the sourcepath (given by the `-sourcepath` option or the classpath if no sourcepath is set). If for a needed both exist and the source file is newer, it is recompiled too.  (They are searched according to the package-structure, too.)

  So in this case you should make sure to pass the `-sourcepath` option so the compiler can find your other source files.

Comment: Yes,actually I gave a try with that and it worked.
like javac /home/kiddo/myfikle.java

Answer (score 1):

set the classpath and path properly and check whether its working fine.

`USAGE:`
`SET CLASSPATH=%<CLASSPATH>%`
`SET PATH=%<PATH_WHERE_JDKS_BIN_LOCATED>%`

The path environment variable must point to the bin directory in the jdk installation...

`USAGE:`
`Variable : JAVA_HOME`
`Value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\bin;.`
`Variable: PATH`
`Value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\lib`

`System Variables :`
`Variable : PATH (This will be there already)`
`Value : %JAVA_HOME%\bin;`

Since the file is not in current directory do the below at the prompt
`$cd home/kiddosr/Kiddo/Java_Programs/ and press enter`
`home/kiddosr/Kiddo/Java_Programs at this point of time type javac Example1.java`

Comment: <CLASSPATH> - should be the directory where my file resides..? for example /home/kiddo/Java_pgms

Comment: SET the path correctly to bin directory of jdk installation and it should work

Comment: FYI..am using Linux
$ PATH=/home/jdk1.6.0_14/bin
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_14"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_14-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
$ CLASSPATH=/home/kiddosr/Kiddo/Java_Programs
$ javac Example1.java
javac: file not found: Example1.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: just ignore the CLASSPATH and give it a try.

Comment: @kiddo: such information better put in your question (there is an edit link) than into a comment, it is better readable there.